# removing auto complete group address

Tags: macos, mail.app

I have a groups mail settings that are not working.

Using the auto complete gave the option of just the group name or the group name with the same name in carrots to the right.

One of the groups follows my preference setting to hide all group recipient email addresses.

The other group shows all the addresses.

To fix the problem I renamed the group and deleted the old name from the On My Mac list of groups.

Now the original name does not appear, but the one with carrots is still there--although I get the warning it does not appear to be a valid email address.

How can I make it go away?

Comment: if I have seen a convoluted question this is the one. So lets try do decipher.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the groups are made and edited in your Contacts not in your mail.

But to hide the group members names and addresses you do that in Mail preferences.

To not show group names/addresses un-check the Addressing.

[image: group]

You can only have show or do not show.